# Why my HDD is being used out of design parameters?

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu 10.04, 11.10 separately (not at the same time) and both of them tell me that my primary hdd is being used out of design parameters.
I installed by using the option use entire disk. And at first boot I get the error and takes me to disk utility. It is a 40GB Samsung HDD IDE drive. Windows and several other tools said that my HDD is healthy.